# Upgrading apscheduler from 3.0.1 to 3.1.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, job-scheduling, apscheduler

I am upgrading apscheduler(3.0.1) to apscheduler(3.1.0).
When I upgraded this I got this error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   from apscheduler.jobstores.base import JobLookupError
   File "/mydir/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
   version_info = tuple(int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in parsed_version.public.split('.'))
   AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'public
```

In the apscheduler 3.0.1 apscheduler/**init**.py file is like

```
  version_info = (3, 0, 5)
  version = '3.0.5'
  release = '3.0.5'
 __version__ = release  # PEP 396
```

In the apscheduler 3.1.0 file changes to

```
 parsed_version = __import__('pkg_resources').get_distribution('APScheduler').parsed_version
 version_info = tuple(int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in parsed_version.public.split('.'))
 version = parsed_version.base_version
 release = __version__ = parsed_version.public
 del parsed_version
```

Because of **parsed_version** has no attribute name public.It is throwing this error.

I edit this file to be like the previous version and then I got a new exception in apscheduler/util.py line 14:

```
 from funcsigs import signature
```

**No module named funcsigs.**

What is the way to upgrading ap-scheduler version safely?

P.S: I am using python 2.7

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using a very ancient version of setuptools. Upgrading that will solve those problems outright, but this incompatibility has already been fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/commit/72769abb97751051fedc47b8c5f13cde3f44bec1). The funcsigs package should also have been installed automatically but your setuptools must be so old it doesn't know how to handle conditional dependencies.

Comment: Got it, Use **pip install -U pip wheel setuptools** to upgrade setup tools and then reinstall **pip install APScheduler==3.1.0**

Comment: Hi,I am using Redis as a Job Store for scheduler.So when I upgrade it and restart it I am getting a warning and then all my scheduled jobs get flushed out.